# render canvas in Django templates

Tags: python, html, django, django-templates, matplotlib

I am using matplotlib library in django app to create diagrams.

I am trying to render canvas object of matplotlib library to django templates with the aid of [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1874642/how-to-use-matplotlib-in-django).

Is there some way to render only canvas object in django templates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is another way to do this. I saved figure using 'figure.savefig' function of matplotlib library in local media directory and loaded the figure using django templates. Views generating figure pass the figure location and name to django templates.